# MVC - Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

When submitting my create form for my model, I get the error:

```
{"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 't_bcim_project_clearance' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}
```

I can see this question has been asked a lot but I've made many changes to my code with no luck at all. I'm sorry in advance that it's so much code, I usually get people complaining in the comments that I don't post enough code so I tried to include everything that could possibly be relevant this time.

The method in my controller that throws this error is:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MaintenanceForm([Bind(Exclude = "project_clearance_id")]t_bcim_project_clearance project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (entities.t_bcim_project_clearance.Any(x => x.project_clearance_id == project.project_clearance_id))
        {
            entities.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
            entities.t_bcim_project_clearance.Add(project);
        }
        entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Maintenance", new { SubmissionNumber = project.Submission_Number, Mode = "Edit" });
    }
    var model = new ProjectViewModel()
    {
        Project = entities.t_bcim_project_clearance.Find(project.project_clearance_id),
        States = states,
        Branches = branches,
        Divisions = divisions,
        ProjectTypes = project_types,
        Statuses = statuses,
        ReadOnly = false,
        Mode = "Edit",
        Cleared = false
    };

    return RedirectToAction("Maintenance", new { SubmissionNumber = project.Submission_Number, Mode = "Edit" });
}
```

at the line `entities.SaveChanges();`. `entities` is my Context class for connecting to the SQL database.

Here's the corresponding GET method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MaintenanceForm(string SubmissionNumber, string Mode, int? id)
{
    if (!Mode.Equals("Edit", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !Mode.Equals("View", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        throw new HttpException(400, "Mode must be either \"Edit\" or \"View\"");
    }

    var model = new ProjectViewModel()
    {
        Project = id.HasValue ? entities.t_bcim_project_clearance.Find(id) : (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SubmissionNumber) ? null : new t_bcim_project_clearance() { Submission_Number = Convert.ToDouble(SubmissionNumber) }),
        Statuses = statuses,
        Divisions = divisions,
        Branches = branches,
        ProjectTypes = project_types,
        States = states,
        Projects = entities.t_bcim_project_clearance.Where(s => s.Submission_Number.ToString().Equals(SubmissionNumber)),
        SubmissionNumber = SubmissionNumber,
        ReadOnly = (Mode == "View"),
        Mode = Mode,
        Cleared = false
    };

    return PartialView("_MaintenanceForm", model);
}
```

My model is a DBmodel. This is the offending property in that model:

```
namespace ProjectClearanceApp.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class t_bcim_project_clearance
    {
        // A lot of other properties
        public int project_clearance_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I created a partial class to add DataAnnotations, which is here:

```
namespace ProjectClearanceApp.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(t_bcim_project_clearanceMetaData))]
    public partial class t_bcim_project_clearance
    {
    }

    public class t_bcim_project_clearanceMetaData
    {
        // a lot of other properties

        [Key]
        [Required]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int project_clearance_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My `project_clearance_id` is set as the primary key for my table, with the Identity Increment = 1.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR**:

- Originally my controller was generating new projects with a precalculated ID, so obviously I removed that
- I added all of the DataAnnotations to the ID property in that partial class
- I used to have `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.project_clearance_id)` at the top of my form but I removed that
- I added the `[Bind(Exclude = "project_clearance_id")]` to the arguments for the POST method

Nothing seems to be working. If anyone sees anything I could change that would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I went into the .edmx diagram for my model, right clicked on the `project_clearance_id`, opened properties, and changed `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`. Now the code works fine when I'm trying to create a new entry, but when I try to edit an existing entry, it creates a new entry with the modified fields and the original entry still exists as it was before.

Comment: This is an entity framework problem, not an MVC problem.

Comment: Okay, so is there something else I need to include in my post? This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: I'm writing you an answer, comments usually just for suggestions/asking additional information/etc.  I know that it doesn't answer your question

Comment: So I repeat is there something else I should include in my post?

Comment: Remove the view code, remove the asp.net, mvc, and razor tags and add the entity framework tag.

Comment: Is this database first or code first?

Comment: It's database first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're attempting to insert/update a database record and in the SQL being generated you're setting the field mapped to the `t_bcim_project_clearance` column to a specific value, however since you have this set to an identity you're not allowed to do this as its value is set automatically.

You need to either make sure the value in the object mapped to this column is not modified or marked as modified.

Instead of using `entities.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified`, set each property is actually in a modified state, to modified instead of the object itself.  To set a property as modified you can do the following:

```
db.Entry(project).Property(x => x.PropertyName).IsModified = true;
```

When you are performing the `.Add()` make sure that the value of the property `project_clearance_id` is set to 0.

**EDIT** Additional info per comments:

- Make sure to include the `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.project_clearance_id)`  from your view if you removed it.  This is needed if you're performing an update.
- Remove the `[Bind(Exclude = "project_clearance_id")]` attribute from your arguments because you need this value if you're performing an update.

Comment: `t_bcim_project_clearance` is not a column, it's the name of the table that my model is built around

Comment: Also when this error is thrown on a new project, `project_clearance_id` is set to 0 at a breakpoint set at the `.Add()`. I also changed the modified state line to your suggestion for every property (first I tried including the `project_clearance_id` in this list, then I tried without it), and it still can't update the project in the table.

Comment: See my edit. I tried this both with the `.IsModified` change you suggested and as my code was before--both result in a new project when I try to edit an existing project.

Comment: That'll always happen because you have `[Bind(Exclude = "project_clearance_id")]`.  You need that value if you're performing an update.  My suggestion is to break up your API to two separate endpoints.  One for creating new and one for updating.

Comment: Oh wow thanks! I removed that exclude and re-added the `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Project.project_clearance_id)` to my form and now it works fine for both create and edit.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Please accept my answer if it resolved your problem.  I added the discussed information for future readers.

Comment: I accepted the answer but if you could edit it to mention that the `.IsModified = true` was not a part of the solution that might be helpful for future readers. Thanks again!